# What's the best way to retrieve daily_budget and lifetime_budget in Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I'm using Insights API to query multiple campaigns data, and I would like to also retrieve daily_budget and lifetime_budget info, but Insights API does not provide these fields.

I know that I can make another request GET to <campaign_id> to retrieve budget info about one campaign, but that would not be efficient to my use case, since I would need to make a lot of extra requests, since I'm dealing with a lot of campaigns for a dashboard.

So, is there a best way to retrieve budget info about multiple campaigns?

Comment: Should be possible using Field Expansion, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/field-expansion/ Instead of `foo/insights(...)`, you can do `foo?fields= daily_budget,lifetime_budget,insights(...)` (Which place needs what kind of braces, round or {}, can need a bit of figuring out.)